# neo4j to csv java heap space error

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher, heap-memory

I'm trying to get into a **csv** some query results from my neo4j DB graph.
I have neo4j 2.2.6 version and I am facing **java.lang.outofmemoryerror : Java Heap Space** error  while I was trying to get all of my nodes with some properties (~1M nodes,~4M rel Graph) to a csv on neo4jshell via import-cypher,export-cypher. When I change the wrapper (wrapper.java.maxmemory,wrapper.java.minmemory to 4g) as I've seen to some other post the error remains and when I change properties (dbms.pagecache.memory to 3g) it crushes before I even open the server.

Comment: Where do you get the error? On the shell? Could you write the command are you running?

Comment: Yes on the shell. The command is (or with import-cypher)                                                              export-cypher -o test10.csv     MATCH (a)-[rel]-(b) WHERE NOT(rel.Weight IS NULL) RETURN id(a) as node,COLLECT(id(b)) as nbhood,COLLECT(rel.Weight) as edgeweight,COUNT(id(b)) as numnodes ORDER by id(a) ASC

Answer (score 0):

To test if it's a heap space problem you do not have to change the page cache, only the heap.

According to http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-performance.html the `initmemory` and `maxmemory` properties take the heap size in MB.

```
# neo4j-wrapper.conf
wrapper.java.initmemory=4000
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4000
```

In addition to the heap settings you can add a `PERIODIC COMMIT` to your `LOAD CSV` query. This will commit regularly to avoid memory errors: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-periodic-commit.html

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM ...
```

Comment: Actually I am using shell commands export-cypher or import-cypher followed by -o outfile.csv {QUERY}

Comment: OK, I overlooked that you export to csv. So if you `MATCH` you complete graph without any filter, you could very well run out of heap space. Can you increase it more? I don't know much about the neo4j-shell-tools. Maybe Michael can help :)